# Getter and Setter problems in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So, i have this bean:

```
<bean id="toMailController" class="com.appointments.kohler.controller.ToEmailController">
    <property name="templateTransformer" ref="templateTransformer"></property>
</bean>
```

and in my **ToEmailController.java** i have this (just the important lines):

```
public ToEmailController extends AbstractController {

public TemplateTransformer _templateTransformer;

@Required
public void setTemplateTransformer(TemplateTransformer templateTransformer) 
{
    this._templateTransformer = templateTransformer;
}

public TemplateTransformer getTemplateTransformer()
{
    return this._templateTransformer;
}

}
```

If i execute this project from Localhost, it runs just fine, but when i put him in weblogic i receive the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'templateTransformer' of bean class [com.appointments.kohler.controller.ToEmailController]: Bean property 'templateTransformer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

But i can't get it. What am i doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: does not using an underscore in your class variable do anything?

Comment: do you have <context:annotation-config /> in your configuration as it is necessary for applying @Required annotation ? and i hate that underscore in property name too.

Comment: @MartinV., yes. I actually use many other properties in this class with **@Required**, but all Strings. This is the only "TemplateTransformer" object.

Comment: @MikeB Actually i have other properties in same class with underscores and it works.

Comment: what do you mean by 'fine in localhost but fail on weblogic'.. what do you use to test in localhost?

Comment: `<property name="templateTransformer" ref="templateTransformer">` -- please update your post and include the bean definition of `templateTransformer`.

Comment: @MikeB Spring bases it's location of a property on the getter/setter, not the underlying class member name, except when using the Autowire annotation, in which case it uses Spring PFM to wire stuff, even when you don't have a getter/setter.

Comment: Try making your TemplateTransformer member private, as I suspect its being public is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thousands of hours, i've tried deploy the project using ANT and it works, after that the BEA WebLogic interface do not gave me the error anymore.

Thanks for every answer!